# toprettyxml() not working while writing back to xml file

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I used python to modify the XML file and want to write the changes in XML back to the file in the pretty form, I am using this code to write
I am using `from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString`

`dom1 = parse("./test.xml")`

`f.write(dom1.toprettyxml(indent="\t", newl="\n", encoding="utf-8"))`

after executing this code it's adding multiple new lines, I think it's adding new line after the new line already present in the XML as the file was already formatted before reading

how to write XML in pretty from python?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `minidom` :

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import xml.dom.minidom

xmlstr = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(dom1)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
with open("pretty.xml", "bw") as f:
    f.write(xmlstr.encode('utf-8'))
```